# Tensoring irreducible representations corresponding to root lattice elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\frak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra with root lattice $Q$ and positive weight space $P^+$. Let $\lambda, \mu \in Q \cap P^+$, with corresponding respective fin-dim irreducible representations $V_{\lambda}$ and $V_{\mu}$. Form the tensor product $V_{\mu} \otimes V_{\lambda}$ and then decompose it into irreducibles
$$
V_{\mu} \otimes V_{\lambda} \simeq V_{\gamma_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus V_{\gamma_m}.
$$
Will the dominant weights $\gamma_i$ still be contained in $Q \cap P^+$ or will they in general only be contained in $P^+$? If they are only contained in $P^+$, then what is a simple example that illustrates this?

Finally, if in general there exist such $\gamma$'s that live outside $Q \cap P^+$, can we categorize/classify the subset of all such dominant weights?

Comment: Not all nonnegative integer combinations of simple roots are nonnegative integer combinations of fundamental weights. In other words, although $Q \subseteq P$ we do not have $Q^+ \subseteq P^+$. Hence your question does not exactly make sense as phrased (the $\lambda,\mu$ may not correspond to fin-dim irreps at all). Do you want to assume that $\lambda, \mu \in Q^+ \cap P^+$ (or more simply $\lambda,\mu \in Q \cap P^+$)?

Comment: Hmm... in Type A ($\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_n$) at least it seems true. Dominant weights are indexed by integer partitions with length at most $n$, modulo $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. The ones living in the root lattice are the ones whose number of boxes is a multiple of $n$. Since when we multiple Schur polynomials $s_{\lambda} s_{\mu}$ the $s_{\nu}$ that appear have $|\nu|=|\lambda|+|\mu|$, if $|\lambda|$ and $|\mu|$ are both multiples of $n$ then so will be $|\nu|$.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be yes? Because $V_{\mu} \otimes V_{\lambda}$ is representation for the adjoint group, and for the adjoint group the highest weights of irreps are in the root lattice.

Comment: @spin: Thanks a lot for the comment. However, could you please explain the line "Because ⊗ is representation for the adjoint group" in more detail?

Comment: Perhaps an even easier way to see what I think spin is saying: if we take weight basis elements $u$ of $V_\mu$ and $v$ of $V_\lambda$ then the weight of $u \otimes v$ will be the sum of the weights of $u$ and of $v$. As spin said, this implies the answer is yes in general.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Yes, that's better. In $V_{\mu} \otimes V_{\lambda}$ every weight is subdominant to $\lambda + \mu$. (I.e. $\lambda + \mu - \nu$ is a sum of roots).  Hence every weight is in the root lattice. What can happen is that $\lambda, \mu \not\in Q$ but $\lambda + \mu \in Q$.

Comment: I think the phrase "positive weight lattice" doesn't belong (since it's not a lattice), but I'm not sure what the $\mathbb Z$-analogue of a cone is, so I didn't change it.

Comment: @LSpice: I think normally people just say "collection" or "set" of dominant (integral) weights $P^+$.

Comment: I have removed the term lattice, in light of the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to summarize what was mentioned in the comments ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440348/tensoring-irreducible-representations-corresponding-to-positive-root-lattice-ele#comment1136048_440348) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440348/tensoring-irreducible-representations-corresponding-to-positive-root-lattice-ele#comment1136051_440348)) and to have this question marked as answered, what follows is the explanation of why the answer is *yes*, the irreps that appear in the decomposition of $V_{\mu}\otimes V_{\lambda}$ will be indexed by root lattice elements.

First notice that every weight that appears in both $V_{\mu}$ and $V_{\lambda}$ must also belong to the root lattice (because we can get to every weight from the highest weight by going down along simple roots: this is a well-known fact about the structure of irreps for semisimple Lie algebras). Then note that $V_{\mu}\otimes V_{\lambda}$ is spanned by $u\otimes v$ where $u$ is a weight basis element of $V_{\mu}$ and $v$ a weight basis element of $V_{\lambda}$. But the weight of $u\otimes v$ is the sum of the weights of $u$ and of $v$. So all the $u\otimes v$ have weights that belongs to the root lattice. In particular, all highest weight vectors do too, hence all irreps that appear are indexed by root lattice elements.

Comment: Of course the fact you mention about weights is indeed well known, but it's relatively shallow compared to the rest of the theory, so I'll just mention it here:  the vectors (in $V$) obtained by applying root vectors (in $\mathfrak g$) to $v$ clearly have weights that differ from that of $v$ by an element of the root lattice, and the collection of these vectors spans a non-$0$ $\mathfrak g$-submodule of $V$, so is all of $V$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440348/tensoring-irreducible-representations-corresponding-to-root-lattice-elements/440449#comment1136072_440449), I mean *repeatedly* applying root vectors.